# Error launching git when using git command prompt

Tags: command-prompt, git

When i try any git command  in command prompt, it shows error .
I tried "git branch" command in command prompt shows below error.

```
error launching git: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have tried googling,but didn't get any proper result for resolving this issue.

Do i need to update Git or is it related to code.

Please Help!

Comment: What happens when you run `git` ?

Comment: check which git you use `where git`

Comment: version is 1.9.5

Comment: Im using Git in visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of struggle , got the way to resolve this issue.

Problem with old version of Git, When i re-installed new version of Git it got resolved.